# Partial Specialization for default_delete

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, enable-if

I would like to specialize default_delete<_Ty> for all objects derived off of MyBaseClass. This was my best attempt:

```
template <typename T>
struct default_delete<typename enable_if<is_base_of<MyBaseClass, T>::value, T>::true_type>
{
    ...
};
```

The compiler seems to be unable to recognize that my type parameter 'T' is being used, which is understandable given that it is 'downstream' from a 'typename' keyword. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting (and preferably a minimal example showing the error).

Comment: Your parameter declaration is an unevaluated context (i.e `T` can't be deduced from the given parameter). `default_delete` must have an extra parameter that allows SFINAE type expressions, otherwise it's not possible (AFAIK). As an alternative, you can implement your own deleter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `enable_if<is_base_of<MyBaseClass, T>::value, T>::type`?

Comment: @Oguk: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used

Comment: @0x499602D2: I think you're right about SFINAE requiring an extra parameter. I'd really like to not have to specify a deleter everytime I declare a unique_ptr for a derived class though...

Comment: @Pradhan: Yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 4):

As 0x499602D2 states in comment, it is not possible without an extra dedicated template parameter. you may use your own deleter as follow:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct my_default_delete : public std::default_delete<T> {}; // default to std::default_delete<T>

template <typename T>
struct my_default_delete<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<MyBaseClass, T>::value>::type>
{
    void operator() (T* ) { /* Your specific implementation */ }
};
```

Comment: The problem here is that the deleter is no longer a 'default' deleter. i.e. I would need to specify this deleter manually like so: unique_ptr<MyDerivedClass, my_delete<MyDerivedClass>>

Comment: @yxrkt: you may add an extra layer: `template <typename T, typename D = my_default_delete<T>> using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, D>;`

Comment: Template aliasing would be amazing, but our project is using vs2012 :(